# jQuery - Updating a script to support touchscreens (scrollview)

Tags: jquery, touch, scrollview, touchscreen

I have been using the [jQuery scroll view](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-scrollview/source/browse/trunk/jquery.scrollview.js?r=2). The script does not appear to support touchscreens so I've spent the better part of a day trying to figure out how I might add touchscreen support to the script.

I considered switching over to jQuery draggable, but it just doesn't work in the same way that the above script seems to work.

Could someone give me some pointers or tips on how to add touch support to this?

Comment: Hello, you should not use the .mousedown(), .mousemove() etc. jQuery methods, but rather the on() method :
`this.i.on({
  'mousedown touchstart': function(e){
    self.startgrab();
    this.xp = e.pageX;
    this.yp = e.pageY;
    return false;
  },
  'mousemove touchmove': function(e){
    if (!self.isgrabbing) return true;
    self.scrollTo(this.xp - e.pageX, this.yp - e.pageY);
    this.xp = e.pageX;
    this.yp = e.pageY;
    return false;
  },
...
});`

Also, you should not use detection from userAgent, rather object and feature detection.

Comment: Lauriss if you can expand your code and provide a working solution, that would be perfect. I used the sample code you provided above and completed the function where you left the ... - the problem is, the script is still not functioning on touchscreens. I am unable to drag things around at all, even though I can on a computer. I think it has to do with the grab events that are set up earlier in the script, though I am unsure. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide an example that is working on desk/laptop but not on touch devices?

Comment: Yes. Check out http://increstedbutte.com/ - the main background image uses scrollview. It works fine on a desk/laptop but not on a touch device (I've tried on my Galaxy S4 and my Google Nexus 7).

Comment: I can offer a bounty of this if you are able to help solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[jquery.mouse2touch.min.js](//cdn.rawgit.com/vpanga/jquery.mouse2touch/master/src/jquery.mouse2touch.min.js)** plug-in to simulate mouse events for touch events.

**[Working DEMO](http://embed.plnkr.co/GzQc6K/preview)**

Note: I saw that you did some code changes in original plug-in [jquery.scrollview.js](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-scrollview/source/browse/trunk/jquery.scrollview.js?r=2) to add touch events. Please use original one, `$("#elment").mouse2touch()` apply mouse event handler behavior to touch events.

> ***Steps to apply this FIX***

- After including [`jquery.min.js`](//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js)
- Include original plug-in for [`jquery.scrollview.js`](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-scrollview/source/browse/trunk/jquery.scrollview.js?r=2)
- Include plug-in [`jquery.mouse2touch.min.js`](//cdn.rawgit.com/vpanga/jquery.mouse2touch/master/src/jquery.mouse2touch.min.js)
- Now you can map mouse events to touch events with this line `$("#map").scrollview().mouse2touch()`

**Below is the code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//increstedbutte.com/wp-content/themes/crestedbutte/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Scroll Demo Plunker!</h1>
  <div id="map">
    <div id="spring" style="opacity: 1;">
      <img width="3800" height="1200" src="http://increstedbutte.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/crested-butte-town-map_spring-v2.jpg" class="attachment- wp-post-image" alt="Crested Butte Town Map - Spring">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//jquery-scrollview.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/jquery.scrollview.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/vpanga/jquery.mouse2touch/master/src/jquery.mouse2touch.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#map").scrollview().mouse2touch();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Added [jquery.mouse2touch.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vpanga/MouseEventSimulatorWithTouch/master/src/jquery.mouse2touch.min.js) github source.

Comment: Thank you for a working solution! I have marked your question as correct and am attempting to award you the bounty, however the option to do so has vanished fromm my screen. I am contacting StackOverflow to query this.

Comment: @ZachNicodemous You're most welcome and I'm glad that helped you. The above mouse2touch plug-in we're using for many apps works very well for existing jQuery mouse event simulation with touch. Also Thank you for the concern to award bounty.

Comment: Updated the reference [jquery.mouse2touch.js](https://github.com/vpanga/jquery.mouse2touch) to new repository.

Answer (score 2):

Just include some touch events to mouse events translation layer, like this:

https://github.com/danielglyde/TouchIt

adding a `$("#yourElement").touchIt();` call in your code will convert every touch event for that object to a mouse event and it should work perfectly as every touchstart is translated to a mousedown and so on.

Be careful though, that if your touchable surface is too large, it may prevent users from scrolling the page. [ https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827 ]

Comment: I am unsure how exactly to go about applying this plugin to the existing Scrollview script. Can you advise?

Comment: @ZachNicodemous just leave your script as it is, add a link to the TouchIt library in the header of the page and add a `$("#yourElement").touchIt();` somewhere in a script on the page (provided `<div id="yourElement">` is the part of the page that should handle touch events).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. First I switched to jQuery UI and tried to make this work with draggable, but was not what I wanted. Then I found a great plugin called pep. It has the same option like jQuery UI but works much beeter, and also works on mobile and has a kinetic drag.

Here you can check the script and see the demos http://pep.briangonzalez.org/

Hope it will help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently someone taught me to use [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) to detect swap touch screen event by which I can modify the default behavior of any of those slider framework which previously do not support touchscreen moving events. Or sometimes can use this to separate swapping layers to show opacity control in certain cases.

I felt it was easy to integrate with other frameworks.

```js
/**
 * requestAnimationFrame and cancel polyfill
 */
(function() {
  var lastTime = 0;
  var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
  for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame =
      window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
  }
  
  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
      var currTime = new Date().getTime();
      var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
      var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
                                 timeToCall);
      lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
      return id;
    };
  
  if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
}());


/**
    * super simple carousel
    * animation between panes happens with css transitions
    */
function Carousel(element)
{
  var self = this;
  element = $(element);
  
  var container = $(">ul", element);
  var panes = $(">ul>li", element);
  
  var pane_width = 0;
  var pane_height = 0;
  var pane_count = panes.length;
  
  var current_pane = 0;
  var carousel_bottom = 0;
  var carousel_top = 0;
  var carousel_head = 85;
  
  var is_expanded;
  
  var _ypos;
  
  
  /**
   * initial
   */
  this.init = function() {
    setPaneDimensions();
    
    $(window).on("load resize orientationchange", function() {
      setPaneDimensions();
      //updateOffset();
    })
  };      
      
  /**
   * set the pane dimensions and scale the container
   */
  function setPaneDimensions() {
    pane_width = element.width();
    panes.each(function() {
      $(this).width(pane_width);
    });
    container.width(pane_width*pane_count);
    
    // Set start point
    carousel_top = $(window).height() - carousel_head;       
    setContainerOffsetY(carousel_top);    
    is_expanded = false;
  };
      
      
  this.updatePaneDimensions = function() {
    var panes = $(">ul>li", element);
    var paneWidth = panes.first().width();
    
    var containerWidth = paneWidth*panes.length;
    
    $(container).css('width', containerWidth);            
    
    // update pane count
    pane_count = panes.length;  
    
    // reset current pane
    this.showPane(current_pane, false);        
  }
  
      
  /**
   * show pane by index
   * @param   {Number}    index
   */
  this.showPane = function(index, animate) {
    // between the bounds
    index = Math.max(0, Math.min(index, pane_count-1));
    current_pane = index;
    
    var offset = -((100/pane_count)*current_pane);
    
    setContainerOffset(offset, true);
  }                
    
  function setContainerOffset(percent, animate) {
    container.removeClass("animate");
    
    if(animate) {
      container.addClass("animate");
    }
    
    var px = ((pane_width * pane_count) / 100) * percent;
    
    if(Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {
      container.css("transform", "translate3d("+ percent +"%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1)");                        
    }
    else if(Modernizr.csstransforms) {
      container.css("transform", "translate("+ percent +"%,0)");
    }
      else {
        var px = ((pane_width*pane_count) / 100) * percent;
        container.css("left", px+"px");
      }
  }

  function setContainerOffsetY(ypos, animate) {
        
    element.removeClass("animate");
    
    if (animate) {
      element.addClass("animate");
    }
    
    _ypos = ypos;
    
    if(Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {      
      element.css("transform", "translate3d(0," + ypos + "px,0) scale3d(1,1,1)");                              
    }
    else if(Modernizr.csstransforms) {
      element.css("transform", "translate(0," + ypos + "px)");
    } 
    else {
      element.css("top", ypos + "px");      
    }
  }
  
  this.next = function() { return this.showPane(current_pane+1, true); };
  this.prev = function() { return this.showPane(current_pane-1, true); };
  
  this.togglePane = function(expand) {
    
    // TODO: 'expand'
    
    if (!is_expanded) {
      // Expand
      self.expand();
    } else {
      // Collapse
      self.collapse();
    }
  }
  
  this.expand = function() {
    setContainerOffsetY(carousel_head, true);    
    is_expanded = true;
  }  
  
  this.collapse = function() {
    setContainerOffsetY(carousel_top, true);        
    is_expanded = false;
  }  
  
  this.throttledTogglePane = _.debounce(self.togglePane, 100);
  
  this.throttledShowPane = _.debounce(function() {
     self.expand();    
  }, 100);
  
  this.throttledHidePane = _.debounce(function() {
    self.collapse();
  }, 100);         
  
  function handleHammer(ev) { 
    
    // disable browser scrolling
    ev.gesture.preventDefault();
    
    switch(ev.type) {
      case 'dragright':
      case 'dragleft':
        // stick to the finger
        var pane_offset = -(100/pane_count) * current_pane;
        var drag_offset = ((100/pane_width) * ev.gesture.deltaX) / pane_count;
        
        // slow down at the first and last pane
        if((current_pane == 0  && ev.gesture.direction == Hammer.DIRECTION_RIGHT) ||
           (current_pane == pane_count-1 && ev.gesture.direction == Hammer.DIRECTION_LEFT)) {
          drag_offset *= .4;
        }
        
        setContainerOffset(drag_offset + pane_offset);
        break;
        
      case 'swipeleft':
        self.next();
        ev.gesture.stopDetect();
        break;
        
      case 'swiperight':
        self.prev();
        ev.gesture.stopDetect();
        break;
        
      case 'release':
        // Left & Right
        // more then 50% moved, navigate
        if(Math.abs(ev.gesture.deltaX) > pane_width/2) {
          if(ev.gesture.direction == 'right') {
            self.prev();
          } else {
            self.next();
          }                        
        }
        else {
          self.showPane(current_pane, true);                                                
        }
                
        if ((ev.gesture.direction == "up") || (ev.gesture.direction == "down")) {
          
          var windowHalf = ($(window).height() - (carousel_head * 2)) / 4;
          
          if(Math.abs(ev.gesture.deltaY) > windowHalf) {                      
            if (is_expanded) {
              self.collapse();
            } else {
              self.expand();               
            }            
          } 
          else { 
            if (is_expanded) {
              self.expand();              
            } else {
              self.collapse();                               
            }
          } 
        }        
        
        break;
        
      case 'tap':
        self.throttledTogglePane();
        ev.gesture.stopDetect();
        break;       
        
      case 'dragup':
        var drag_offset = carousel_top + ev.gesture.deltaY;
        
        if (is_expanded) {          
          drag_offset = carousel_head + ev.gesture.deltaY;
//           drag_offset *= .4;
        }

        setContainerOffsetY(drag_offset);
        break;
        
      case 'dragdown':        
        var drag_offset = carousel_head + ev.gesture.deltaY;  
        
        if (!is_expanded) {
          console.log('not expanded', carousel_top, ev.gesture.deltaY)
          drag_offset = carousel_top + ev.gesture.deltaY;
        }
        
        setContainerOffsetY(drag_offset);
        break;
       
      case 'swipeup':
        console.log('swipeup')
        self.throttledShowPane();
        ev.gesture.stopDetect();
        break;        
        
      case 'swipedown':
        console.log('swipedown')
        self.throttledHidePane();
        ev.gesture.stopDetect();
        break;
    }
  }
  
  element.hammer({ drag_lock_to_axis: true })
  .on("tap release dragleft dragright swipeleft swiperight dragup dragdown swipeup swipedown", handleHammer);  
}

var carousel = new Carousel("#carousel");
carousel.init();
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  
  /* via http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#seigaiha */
  background-color:#ddd;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(circle at 100% 150%, #ddd 24%, white 25%, white 28%, #ddd 29%, #ddd 36%, white 36%, white 40%, transparent 40%, transparent),
    radial-gradient(circle at 0    150%, #ddd 24%, white 25%, white 28%, #ddd 29%, #ddd 36%, white 36%, white 40%, transparent 40%, transparent),
    radial-gradient(circle at 50%  100%, white 10%, #ddd 11%, #ddd 23%, white 24%, white 30%, #ddd 31%, #ddd 43%, white 44%, white 50%, #ddd 51%, #ddd 63%, white 64%, white 71%, transparent 71%, transparent),
    radial-gradient(circle at 100% 50%, white 5%, #ddd 6%, #ddd 15%, white 16%, white 20%, #ddd 21%, #ddd 30%, white 31%, white 35%, #ddd 36%, #ddd 45%, white 46%, white 49%, transparent 50%, transparent),
    radial-gradient(circle at 0    50%, white 5%, #ddd 6%, #ddd 15%, white 16%, white 20%, #ddd 21%, #ddd 30%, white 31%, white 35%, #ddd 36%, #ddd 45%, white 46%, white 49%, transparent 50%, transparent); 
  background-size:100px 50px;  
}


#carousel, #carousel li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;            
}

#carousel {
/*   position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; */
}

#carousel ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}        

#carousel {            
/*   overflow: hidden; */
  width:100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#carousel.animate {
  -webkit-transition: all .15s;
  -moz-transition: all .15s;
  -o-transition: all .15s;
  transition: all .15s;
}


#carousel ul.animate {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

#carousel ul {
  transform: translate3d(0%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#carousel ul {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  position: relative;
}

#carousel li {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#carousel li {
  /*height: 85px;*/
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .8;
}

/* Sugar */

#carousel li h2 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
/*  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
*/  
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#carousel li p {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hammer.js Carousel</title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="carousel">
        <ul>
          <li class="pane1">
            <h2>Swipe <small>left, right, up or down..</small></h2>
            <p>DIY Shoreditch chambray ugh American Apparel fingerstache. Literally keytar cardigan pour-over letterpress kogi, direct trade Brooklyn Blue Bottle tousled. Cred typewriter flexitarian street art bitters forage, Tonx pour-over aesthetic meh quinoa dreamcatcher Brooklyn. 90's master cleanse beard, letterpress stumptown messenger bag sustainable kogi banjo. Kogi mixtape artisan fashion axe Odd Future vegan. Dreamcatcher scenester you probably haven't heard of them, art party Williamsburg chillwave Etsy Helvetica photo booth ethical gluten-free pop-up Schlitz distillery pickled. Thundercats actually hoodie, Helvetica art party whatever YOLO bespoke pop-up Odd Future freegan Pitchfork Etsy literally.</p>
            <p>Roof party blog lo-fi banh mi mixtape fingerstache.  Deep v Neutra locavore kale chips.  Fap PBR meggings, master cleanse trust fund four loko semiotics pickled gastropub umami.  Etsy kale chips asymmetrical skateboard food truck.  Direct trade  American Apparel Blue Bottle lo-fi raw denim.  Pitchfork disrupt paleo vinyl food truck vegan, yr cardigan whatever lo-fi 3 wolf moon craft beer biodiesel literally mustache.  Hella scenester Neutra XOXO, YOLO iPhone raw denim swag Vice.</p><p>Plaid kitsch tofu, Cosby sweater Godard sriracha Thundercats kogi swag paleo hella hashtag cred beard.  Messenger bag jean shorts meh gastropub.  Banksy tattooed photo booth, viral Vice quinoa keytar fingerstache stumptown single-origin coffee chia.  +1 hella 8-bit sriracha ennui pork belly, Bushwick artisan Echo Park swag meh pour-over plaid quinoa fingerstache.  Before they sold out semiotics leggings stumptown, post-ironic XOXO actually brunch fanny pack food truck PBR iPhone chambray High Life.  Ugh selfies freegan quinoa, PBR Shoreditch sartorial Odd Future salvia pug keffiyeh ethnic blog.  Squid twee Brooklyn, banjo ugh salvia gluten-free.</p>
            <p>Roof party blog lo-fi banh mi mixtape fingerstache.  Deep v Neutra locavore kale chips.  Fap PBR meggings, master cleanse trust fund four loko semiotics pickled gastropub umami.  Etsy kale chips asymmetrical skateboard food truck.  Direct trade  American Apparel Blue Bottle lo-fi raw denim.  Pitchfork disrupt paleo vinyl food truck vegan, yr cardigan whatever lo-fi 3 wolf moon craft beer biodiesel literally mustache.  Hella scenester Neutra XOXO, YOLO iPhone raw denim swag Vice.</p><p>Plaid kitsch tofu, Cosby sweater Godard sriracha Thundercats kogi swag paleo hella hashtag cred beard.  Messenger bag jean shorts meh gastropub.  Banksy tattooed photo booth, viral Vice quinoa keytar fingerstache stumptown single-origin coffee chia.  +1 hella 8-bit sriracha ennui pork belly, Bushwick artisan Echo Park swag meh pour-over plaid quinoa fingerstache.  Before they sold out semiotics leggings stumptown, post-ironic XOXO actually brunch fanny pack food truck PBR iPhone chambray High Life.  Ugh selfies freegan quinoa, PBR Shoreditch sartorial Odd Future salvia pug keffiyeh ethnic blog.  Squid twee Brooklyn, banjo ugh salvia gluten-free.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="pane2">
            <h2>...or drag...</h2>
              <p>Occupy Thundercats sriracha, DIY Shoreditch chambray ugh American Apparel fingerstache. Literally keytar cardigan pour-over letterpress kogi, direct trade Brooklyn Blue Bottle tousled. Cred typewriter flexitarian street art bitters forage, Tonx pour-over aesthetic meh quinoa dreamcatcher Brooklyn. 90's master cleanse beard, letterpress stumptown messenger bag sustainable kogi banjo. Kogi mixtape artisan fashion axe Odd Future vegan. Dreamcatcher scenester you probably haven't heard of them, art party Williamsburg chillwave Etsy Helvetica photo booth ethical gluten-free pop-up Schlitz distillery pickled. Thundercats actually hoodie, Helvetica art party whatever YOLO bespoke pop-up Odd Future freegan Pitchfork Etsy literally.</p>
              <p>Roof party blog lo-fi banh mi mixtape fingerstache.  Deep v Neutra locavore kale chips.  Fap PBR meggings, master cleanse trust fund four loko semiotics pickled gastropub umami.  Etsy kale chips asymmetrical skateboard food truck.  Direct trade  American Apparel Blue Bottle lo-fi raw denim.  Pitchfork disrupt paleo vinyl food truck vegan, yr cardigan whatever lo-fi 3 wolf moon craft beer biodiesel literally mustache.  Hella scenester Neutra XOXO, YOLO iPhone raw denim swag Vice.</p><p>Plaid kitsch tofu, Cosby sweater Godard sriracha Thundercats kogi swag paleo hella hashtag cred beard.  Messenger bag jean shorts meh gastropub.  Banksy tattooed photo booth, viral Vice quinoa keytar fingerstache stumptown single-origin coffee chia.  +1 hella 8-bit sriracha ennui pork belly, Bushwick artisan Echo Park swag meh pour-over plaid quinoa fingerstache.  Before they sold out semiotics leggings stumptown, post-ironic XOXO actually brunch fanny pack food truck PBR iPhone chambray High Life.  Ugh selfies freegan quinoa, PBR Shoreditch sartorial Odd Future salvia pug keffiyeh ethnic blog.  Squid twee Brooklyn, banjo ugh salvia gluten-free.</p>
            <p>Roof party blog lo-fi banh mi mixtape fingerstache.  Deep v Neutra locavore kale chips.  Fap PBR meggings, master cleanse trust fund four loko semiotics pickled gastropub umami.  Etsy kale chips asymmetrical skateboard food truck.  Direct trade  American Apparel Blue Bottle lo-fi raw denim.  Pitchfork disrupt paleo vinyl food truck vegan, yr cardigan whatever lo-fi 3 wolf moon craft beer biodiesel literally mustache.  Hella scenester Neutra XOXO, YOLO iPhone raw denim swag Vice.</p>
          </li>
            <li class="pane3"><h2>...or swipe...</h2></li>
            <li class="pane4"><h2>..or drag...</h2></li>
            <li class="pane5"><h2>Dit is het einde!</h2></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.0.6/hammer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.dfjs.co.uk/slider/jquery.hammer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you switch to other jQuery scrolling script,check [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao4HbHsCLP0YdEhnZVh1WGZSbXloekZiNWlaNElnTnc&usp=sharing#gid=0), in which compares many scrolling script.